# how to know if the Linux os i am using has the specific system calls?

Tags: c++, c, linux-kernel, network-programming, busybox

I am building a firmware application for a busy box. My application uses all the socket related system calls, but when i run the program, the client is not able to connect to the server even though the server port is open (checked with netstat -nl) .

Is it possible to check on the busy box that, if the system calls i am using are enabled on the operating system?

Update: The program to connect to a server socket was working on  device1 and the same program was not working on device2. The device2 has the update on the kernel, this is the reason i was thinking if some system calls are not supported.

The error given was errno - 97 after connect system call. which is the protocol family not supported.

i have observed that the problem is caused in the below is the part of code.

ADDRINFOA   hints;
  PADDRINFOA  result;

hints.ai_family = AF_INET;

```
if (getaddrinfo (hostname, NULL, &hints, &result) == 0)
```

{

```
memcpy (sockaddr, result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen);

freeaddrinfo (result);
```

}

after the Getaddrinfo the sockaddr.ss_family is 0. Which i expect to be 2

What am i doing wrong here? any help?

Comment: First of all, please don't use multiple language tags. Only use the one for the language you're actually program in. Secondly, please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Lastly, what error do you get when attempting to connect? You *did* check what error the [`connect`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html) call gave you?

Comment: There is no such  thing as disabling system calls. Some functions on your system may be blocked SELinux security system, but it does NOT disable system calls, it blocks certain I/O operations based on security context. Your question is example of X/Y problem. You have to diagnose why you don't get connection. Do you have firewall in place? what error codes returned from calls? Are you able to ping, traceroute toward destination?

Comment: Thanks for the inputs "Some programming dude", and thanks for not down voting. I am deleting this question as i found that my problem is due some socket error during connection (errno 97 - address family not supported). i will post a separate well formed question.

Comment: @Swift - configuring a kernel to not have specific syscalls (e.g. `CONFIG_NETWORK=n`) probably counts as "disabling" them.

Comment: The way to check it at runtime is to run a program that performs the syscall and see if the call fails and sets errno to `ENOSYS`. (Now - if your server is running and listening on a port, you probably have issues elsewhere, e.g. by trying to use protocols the kernel does not support, or issues with a firewall, or routing - not by missing syscalls)

Comment: @TobySpeight never saw effect of those in real world and while i surmise they may return ENOSYS if programmer tries use those functions to connect to actual network, that's why I asked about error values. Same functions are used for different purposes where they should work with CONFIG_NETWORK=n (again, in theory)

Comment: The problem most likely lies elsewhere, as commented by nos - you'll want to check whether you have iptables rules active, for example, and test connectivity (preferably using `netcat` or similar, to rule out programming errors).  Then come back with a question that's backed with your research.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not compiled your kernel in an uncommon configuration, you should have all network functionality included (this means your network related system calls should be included)

Posting your failing code could be an idea, already signalled in the comments (follow @SomeProgrammerDude's comment)

**EDIT**

System calls use fixed, registered identifiers (internal integer ids) to select the proper system call and this must work with different kernels and different standard libraries that bound the identifier names by which we know the syscall.  If you modify any of these, you break the stdlib interface (or the kernel) So they are fixed.  Even when functionality is not implemented, the syscall entry point must work.  Normally, on system calls not actually implemented, there's a stub function that limits to give an error on call.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19313847)

Comment: Yes, it provides it.  But it is not the one people wants to hear.  The set of system calls is not updatable at runtime (on a load module or unload module basis) so they are all included (possibly with stub implementations, that give an error when tried) in a running kernel.

Comment: The question should be voted for close on a basis on that the OP didn't post any code at all, so no diagnostic can be made, only to speculate on what he can be doing.  System calls are all included (even nonworking ones) in every kernel built.  The only possibility of having a non-present syscall is to edit the source code and eliminate it.

Comment: The first part of your answer is speculation, not fit for answers. The second part, although factual, does not answer the question.